# htaccess RewriteRule images folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Now I am using this code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule   /images(.*)  /images/$1
RewriteRule   /css(.*)  /css/$1
RewriteRule   /js(.*)  /js/$1
```

But there is a problem when I have added some third party plugins which uses this same folders but not on root folder, but on their subfolders, so I now need to change this so that it will only apply for folder /images/ and not for example /plugins/myplugin/templates/images/

Comment: I just saw another question of this OP. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800070/htaccess-rewriterule-php-to). Doesn't say nothing, doesn't accept or reject the answers. Be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try incorporating the `^` regex symbol denoting the beginning of the string:

```
RewriteRule   ^/?images(.*)  /images/$1
RewriteRule   ^/?css(.*)  /css/$1
RewriteRule   ^/?js(.*)  /js/$1
```

Now these will only match URL's like:

```
http://mysite.com/imagessomething.jpg
http://mysite.com/csssomething.css
http://mysite.com/jssomething.js
```

but not when they are in a subfolder.

Comment: That doesn't work. I need http://mysite.com/images/*.jpg to be included but not http://mysite.com/somethingelse/images/*.jpg

Comment: @MarkFrost `http://mysite.com/somethingelse/images/` won't be included (like I said). The `^` means **the beginning of the URI**, so, `^/?images` will never match `/something/images` since `/images` isn't the beginning of the URI.

Comment: Well the problem now is where I have URLs like domain.com/news/1/NewsName - there is no images now (probably because it looks like it's in sub/sub folder).

Comment: @MarkFrost You need to add `<base href="/">` to the header of your pages or change all your links to images/styles/scripts to absolute paths.

Comment: I need http://example.com/uploads/image/7474/23b3825eb250bc00e900142996b4d398_600.jpg was loaded from another folder, your example is not helps me. :(