# Removing .php extension with /

Tags: php, .htaccess

Well i know how to remove .php extension but i have a question.

```
www.example.com/one/two/three
```

In this type of address, what does "one" and "two" means. Are they folders or just link with out extension.

And how to create like this.

Comment: It can be folder and it can be variables. Use `htaccess` with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically its an MVC route. It means controller/action/param.

You can create it using htaccess by redirecting request to index.php
The following will skip existing files from being redirected to the index.php file, and they'll be served normally

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

After that, when request is passed to your index.php file, you can parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and load classes that suit your request.

So if, for example, you have request news/read/1, you should find and call class **News** method **read** with argument **1**.

Answer (score 0):

Those are can be folders or variables.. using [htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800070/htaccess-rewriterule-php-to) u can create links like that..

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```